# Gas usage difference between Remix and Ganache/public networks

Tags: remix, gas, metamask, solc, gas-price

I'm trying to integrate a contract into a front end with MetaMask and getting different gas amounts depending on the network and compile options I use.

- Remix ("Enable Optimization" checked): 90,410
- Ganache/Rinkeby (no optimization): 112,500
- Ganache/Rinkeby (with optimization): 101,431

I actually got the optimization settings from the Remix GitHub page here: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/14c22658ef5b6aa49ee31d5c92882c8a3c9e42fe/src/app/compiler/compiler-input.js

My `solc` configuration looks like this.  The only change I'm making to optimize is to add the `optimizer` setting below.

```
let jsonContractSource = JSON.stringify({
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'Task': {
          content: source,
       },
    },
    settings: { 
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      outputSelection: {
          '*': {
              '*': ['abi',"evm.bytecode"],   
          },
      },
    },
});

module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(jsonContractSource)).contracts.Task.MyContract;
```

I spent a decent amount of time trying to optimize the gas consumption of the function itself in Remix, but I think I must be missing something in terms of solc configuration.

As an additional question, are there any risks associated with using solc's optimizer?

Comment: What code are you testing with? If you use the same version of the compiler and optimization parameters they should produce the same gas consumption.

Comment: I just noticed a few minutes ago that if I test in Ganache or Rinkeby through Remix, I get a similar gas cost to a contract compiled with `solc`.  I think it might just be an issue with Remix's Javascript VM not being reflective of real networks.